# ViewBag change using ajax in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, exchange-server, viewbag

ViewBag, ViewData, TempData are called just once at the first time when I call the view?

And never change if I don't refresh the page?

Because I want to change using Ajax (every 10 sec, I call Ajax)

Plz See below code,

==================== in Controller... =======================

```
 public ActionResult OriginView()
 {

      ViewBag.IntData = 1;

      return View();

 }


 public JsonResult ChangeViewBag(int CurrentInterval)
 {

      ViewBag.IntData = CurrentInterval;

      return Json(new{IntData=CurrentInterval},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

 }
```

================= in OriginView.cshtml... =======================

```
 var CurrentInterval = 2

 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ChangeViewBag","Controller")', {CurrentInterval:CurrentInterval},function(response){

    @*CurrentInterval++ every ten sec, I want to use CHANGED ViewBag here!*@

    alert(@ViewBag.IntData) @*but **Result is still 1**, unchanged!*@

    alert(response.IntData) @*ofcourse I can use it in this way. *@

    @* but I should use below ASP.NET CODE

    @{
       string TimeData = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(**ViewBag.IntData**).ToString();
    }

    ***The position is impossible to javascript variable.*** right?*@
 });
```

.Net genius please!!!
If it's impossible, Any Idea?

Comment: The code is doing just what you've asked. Maybe you can spend more time on the narrative about what you want to do instead? You seem to be relying on the ViewBag a lot in the javascript, which would be like expecting a US Battleship to be involved in my making a peanut butter sandwhich in Kansas.

Comment: Got it! appreciate for engaging me!!!

Comment: And yet, you didn't give a narrative. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2):

`ViewData` / `ViewBag`(this is a wrapper around `ViewData`) are used to pass data between a controller to a view and **they are re-created in every request whether it's AJAX or normal**. They don't help you to maintain state **:(**